# Importing a selection of columns from dataframes

Tags: r, import, tidyverse, fread, data-wrangling

I am trying to import multiple **dta** files without typing individual import code lines and without wasting too much loading time.

There are two challenges. First, each dataframe has its own idiosyncratic name. Think of it as multiple state names: Arizona, Alabama, Texas, etc.

The second challenge is that I only want to import a handful of columns. For instance, I just want to import columns labeled state, id, and temperature. I don’t need to spend extra time for columns that I am going to de-select right away.

I don’t need to rbind these files once they import them.

To restate: I want to import columns state, id, and temperature from dta files Alabama, Arizona, and Texas

Here is some sample data:

```
set.seed(100)
arizona <- data.frame(state= "AZ",
                        id= 1:100,
                        temperature= runif(100, min=40, max=80),
                        var1= runif(100, min=10, max=20),
                        var2= runif(100, min=50, max=70))

alabama <- data.frame(state= "AL",
                        id= 1:50,
                        temperature= runif(50, min=30, max=70),
                        var1= runif(50),
                        var2= runif(50, min=50, max=70))

texas <- data.frame(state= "TX",
                        id= 1:120,
                        temperature= runif(120, min=35, max=75),
                        var1= runif(120, min=10, max=20),
                        var2= runif(120, min=50, max=70))
```

Thank you,

Comment: There are several programs that use the file extension dta, in your case, what are those files? What are the packages/functions you are using to read them?

Comment: Fread to read files

Comment: @YouLocalRUser If you think that `data.table::fread` can read dta files, then you should say which of the several types of dta files you are claiming value for fread. It CANNOT read Stata dta files, at least the ones of the same version as are in the pkg:haven examples directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two read functions for Stata files in my installed packages, but only haven has a column selection option within the code. Something like this untested code:

```
libary(haven)
in_st_list <- lapply( paste( c("Alabama", "Arizona", "Texas"), ".dta", sep=""),
        read_dta, 
        col_select= all_of( c('state', 'id', 'temperature') )
       )
```

You will get a list of 3 dataframes if I haven't made any syntactic or substantive errors.